# Dynamic "WHERE IN" on IQueryable (linq to SQL)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have a LINQ to SQL query returning rows from a table into an IQueryable object.

```
IQueryable<MyClass> items = from table in DBContext.MyTable
select new MyClass
{
 ID = table.ID,
 Col1 = table.Col1,
 Col2 = table.Col2
}
```

I then want to perform a SQL "WHERE ... IN ...." query on the results. This works fine using the following. (return results with id's ID1 ID2 or ID3)

```
sQuery = "ID1,ID2,ID3";
string[] aSearch = sQuery.Split(',');
items = items.Where(i => aSearch.Contains(i.ID));
```

What I would like to be able to do, is perform the same operation, but not have to specify the i.ID part. So if I have the string of the field name I want to apply the "WHERE IN" clause to, how can I use this in the .Contains() method?

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of ways to do this.  One way is to use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).  Another way is to use [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Comment: Robert, thanks for your post. 
Dynamic Linq looks like it will allow me to specify the field as a string based query, which is what I want, but I'm not sure it supports the SQL IN clause.
Predicate Builder looks like i could create an expression by chaining Predicate.Or expressions together, but i don't know how i can use my column name string in each of these. I've attempted though reflection, and calling the Equals method, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your have to build an expression tree. It will end up looking like this (partial code, will not compile). This one does both contains and equals. Used in this project: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/15/asp-net-mvc-paging-sorting-filtering-a-list-using-modelmetadata.aspx

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(filterType, propertyName);
var left = Expression.Property(param, filterType.GetProperty(propertyName));
var right = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, modelMetaData.ModelType);

LambdaExpression predicate = null;

if (searchFilterAttribute.FilterType == FilterType.Contains)
{
    var methodContains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var filterContains = Expression.Call(left, methodContains, right);
    predicate = Expression.Lambda(filterContains, param);
}
else
{
    var expr = Expression.Equal(left, right);
    predicate = Expression.Lambda(expr, param);

}

var expression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable), 
    "Where", 
    new Type[] { queryable.ElementType },
    queryable.Expression,
    predicate);

queryable = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(expression);
```

I may rewrite this into a reusable extension method (it is too specific to that project at the moment) and blog about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raj, but I think that will allow me to check if a field contains a string. I want to perform an SQL IN equivalent using contains. i.e. array contains field, rather than field contains string.